# How to automatically split text in two columns in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have often blocks with text split in two columns. Problem is that I have to determine where to split the text so that it doesn't end out of the frame, and whenever i made any modification in the frame I have to re-determine where to split. Also, the manual split looks kind of ugly at times. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block title}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.4\textwidth}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.
    \column{.4\textwidth}
\end{columns}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course in my actual code I don't have a block as big as frame, this is just for showing purpose.

I would like the text to automatically move to the second column when the end of the block or frame is reached. Is this possible with the `columns` environment? If not, is there any way to do it?

Comment: sorry for the duplicate, didn't find the original question...

Comment: no worries, finding duplicates is hard, it helps if you remember answering the same question a day or two ago:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `multicols` environment from the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package instead (of course, now the columns will all have the same width):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block title}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.
\end{multicols}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]